# Javascript: Cant fetch value of input number box

Tags: javascript, user-input

Hello almighty internetz!

Im totally new on javascript, and i cant get the script to fetch numbers from input boxes, plus the sums together and write it out.

Have been sitting on Google for an hour now, so im asking you guys/girls for help!

http://jsfiddle.net/heWM2/5/

```
<form action="" id="brod">
    <p>Pris per kartong
        <input name="Prisperkartong" type="number" id="priskart" name="pris">
    </p>
    <p>Antal kartonger i leverans
        <input name="Kartongilev" type="number" id="kartilev">
    </p>
    <input type="button" onClick="calculateTotal()" value="Räkna">
    <div id="print"></div>
</form>
```

And the Javascript:

```
function getPrisperkartong() {
var Prisperkartong = parseInt(document.brod.priskart.value, 10);
if (isNaN(Prisperkartong)) return;
document.bord.priskart.value = Prisperkartong;
}

function getKartongilev() {
var Kartongilev = parseInt(document.brod.kartilev.value, 10);
if (isNaN(Kartongilev)) return;
document.bord.kartilev.value = Kartongilev;
}
function calculateTotal() {
var total = getPrisperkartong() + getKartongilev();

var divobj = document.getElementById('print');
divobj.style.display = 'block';
divobj.innerHTML = "Pris $" + total;
}
```

Comment: So you want your numbers from the input to be fetched in a box and then generate the sum of them? That's it?

Comment: `Have been sitting on Google for an hour now` You should _debug_. For a lot more than just an hour...

Comment: As i said, iam a total java noob. :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are accessing the input boxes through the form, you need to use the `name` field to identify the form as well as the input boxes.  Your `get` functions should also return the value, not assign it back to the original input box. See this updated fiddle for a fixed, working example.

http://jsfiddle.net/heWM2/6/